# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically when running doc = nlp('')

Tags: python, spacy

When running this line of code:
doc=nlp('Hello world.')
I get this error message: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

This error occurs only when the text includes spaces.

Here is my code:

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

doc = nlp(u'Hello world')

doc._.has_coref
doc._.coref_clusters
```

Comment: Can you try running your code in an environment where you can get a more detailed error message? With just this information there's not really any way to tell what's going on.